# Textbox acts like it is disabled

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, textbox

Currently I try to copy an existing HTML contact page into my new ASP.NET website, but for some reason I cannot use the textbox name, email and phone (it looks disabled). The funny part is that I can use the textbox "Message". Below the HTML code:

```
<form id="contactForm" class="form-style" name="sentMessage" novalidate="">
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="text_cont form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="You Name" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter name" class="form-control"><span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="text_cont form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="You Email" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter email" class="form-control"><span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <div class="text_cont form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
        <input id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="You Phone" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter phone number" class="form-control"><span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="text_cont form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
        <textarea id="message" cols="40" rows="10" placeholder="Message" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message." aria-invalid="false" class="form-control"></textarea><span class="help-block text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-12"><div id="success"></div></div>
<div class="col-lg-12"><p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send Message</button></p></div>
```

It works when I run the above code in just an HTML file. Looks like there is something wrong with my configuration in ASP.NET? Well, I have no idea.

My settings:

- NET Framework 3.5
- Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

I hope you could help me out.

Thanks.

Jamie

Comment: Can you add closing tag to input tags as we should have closing tags for everything we will have text or content else it would become a void element.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are not getting the the name tag before name because if you want name then type name before 
    { name: }

Comment: No, please read my question. You don't understand what I mean.